# I am getting error when I run the Android application: app: dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug

Tags: android

> Failed to transform
> 'C:\Users\Rahul.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android.gms\play-services-tasks\11.8.0\b6dad60aa213db8f46fbd758dff9e301701ff157\play-services-tasks-11.8.0.aar'
> using Jetifier. Reason: IOException, message: Data error (cyclic
> redundancy check). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

I am using these to library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

Comment: check your layout files and other classes. Android studio compilation errors funnel into databinding. It's infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have done the `Clean -> Rebuild -> Invalidate Caches -> Delete .idea and .gradle folders` routine.

Considering you've done all these

1. Update your library `11.8.0` it seems outdated
2. Use the firebase bom instead of independent versioning .

If all else fails remove the firebase implementation and check if the error persists

Comment: done all these but not working